# getStaticPaths() is unable to fetch the paths. I got serialize error when i call this particular api route

Tags: next.js

I am fetching all posts from the backend from the API call `http://localhost:3000/api/jobs` and it is working perfectly by using getstaticProps(). Now I want to get a particular post based on slug and my API call is `http://localhost:3000/api/jobs/:slug` and it perfectly working API call But whenever I used the code shown below for dynamic routes it shows me a server error on the frontend and unable to fetch particular post data.

**[slug].js**

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${API}/jobs`);
    const post = await res.json();
    const paths = post.map(job => {
        return {
            params: { slug: job.slug }

        }
    })

    return {

        paths,
        fallback:true
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
    const slug = ctx.params.slug;

    const [job, photo] = await Promise.all([
        fetch(`${API}/jobs/${slug}`).then(r => r.json()),
        `${API}/jobs/photo/${slug}`
    ]);
    if (!job) {
        return {
      notFound:true
        }
      }
    return {
        props: {
            job,
            photo

        },
        revalidate:60
    }

}
```

Also whenever I used another API call like `http://localhost:3000/api/jobs-edit` which has the same function as that of `http://localhost:3000/api/jobs` inside getStaticPaths() then it performs well and gives us single post data.
What can be the problem?

Comment: this line not make sense that ${API}/jobs/photo/${slug} also must be in fetch function const [job, photo] = await Promise.all([
        fetch(`${API}/jobs/${slug}`).then(r => r.json()),
        `${API}/jobs/photo/${slug}`
    ]);

Comment: what error did you get?